# "At most one" versus "at most finitely many"

Tags: lo.logic, reverse-math

As shown in Simpson's excellent [Subsystems of Second Order Arithmetic](https://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/sosoa), the ‘big five’ system ATR$_0$ from second-order reverse mathematics is equivalent to the following principle:

*For arithmetical $\varphi$ such that $(\forall n)(\exists \text{ at most one } X)\varphi(X, n)$, there is $Z$ such that $(\forall m)(m\in Z\leftrightarrow (\exists X)\varphi(X,m))$.*

My question is whether this ‘at most one’ comprehension principle is also equivalent to the following ‘at most finitely many’ principle, where $w^{1^*}$ is a finite sequence of sets of length $\lvert w\rvert$.

*For arithmetical $\varphi$ such that
$$
(\forall n)(\exists w^{1^*})(\forall X)\Bigl[\varphi(X, n)\rightarrow (\exists i< \lvert w\rvert)(X=w(i))\Bigr],\tag{*}\label{star}
$$
there is $Z$ such that $(\forall m)(m\in Z\leftrightarrow (\exists X)\varphi(X,m))$.*

Note that the condition \eqref{star} guarantees that there are only finitely many $X$ satisfying $\varphi(X,n)$, for fixed $n$.

Comment: A related phenomenon is the fact in set theory that a set is hereditarily ordinal definable if and only if it is hereditarily ordinal algebraic. (Algebraic means that the object has a property that only finitely many objects have.) See http://dx.doi.org/10.1215/00294527-3542326

Comment: Another related phenomenon, which is classical and may  have motivated the question, is that finite-to-one, or even countable-to-one, projections of Borel sets are Borel.

Comment: Is $|w|$ fixed here, or not? That is, should I read $(\ast)$ as saying $$(\exists l) (\forall n)(\exists w : [0,l-1] \to \mathbb N) (\forall X)\Bigl[\varphi(X, n)\rightarrow (\exists i< l )(X=w(i))\Bigr]\tag{*1}$$ or should I rather read it as saying $$(\forall n)(\exists l) (\exists w : [0,l-1] \to \mathbb N) (\forall X)\Bigl[\varphi(X, n)\rightarrow (\exists i< l )(X=w(i))\Bigr]\tag{*2}$$? (In either case I assume some coding is used to talk about having a function $w : [0,l-1] \to \mathbb N$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is positive, assuming extra induction, and a sketch is as follows.

Let $\varphi(X,n)$ be as in (*).

1. Define an analytic code $A_n$ as follows $X\in A_n\leftrightarrow \varphi(X, n)$.
2. Use induction (say for $\Sigma_2^1$-formulas) to show that $A_n$ can be enumerated (as a finite sequence).
3. Now use V.4.10 from [Subsystems of Second-order Arithmetic](https://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/sosoa) to show that $\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n$ can be enumerated, say by $(X_m)_{m\in \mathbb{N}}$.
4. Then for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we have

$$
(\exists X\subset \mathbb{N})\varphi(X, n)\leftrightarrow (\exists m\in \mathbb{N})\varphi(X_m, n),
$$
and we are done. Note that step 3. makes use of ATR$_0$.